I want to transform a CDATA under an element to an attribute value and keep the new lines
I want to transform an XML file to another XML file using XSLT, and replace the CDATA of some XML elements by an attribute.
I also need to keep the new line characters, of course I need to convert those I find in the CDATA content to "
".
For example, if I have:
<description>
  This is a description on
  more than one line
</description>

I want to have the following result:
<description value="This is a description on&#xA;   more than one line"/>

I wrote the following XSL file to do this:
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:variable name="new-line" select="'&#10;'" /> 

  <xsl:template name="writeParam" match="/">
    <xsl:choose>
       <xsl:when test="description">      
          <xsl:element name="description">
             <xsl:variable name="temp">
                <xsl:value-of select="description"/>
             </xsl:variable>    
             <xsl:attribute name="value">            
                <xsl:value-of select="translate($temp, $new-line, '&#xA;')" />
             </xsl:attribute>               
          </xsl:element>
       </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>

But instead I have the following result:
<description value="&#10;   This is a description on&#10;   more than one line&#10;"/>

It seems that the translate function is never called, why is it not working?

I am not sure what you think you need the transform function for, if you put a line break into an attribute value of the result tree the serializer will make sure it is escaped as e.g. &#10; or &#xA;. So <xsl:template match="description"><description value="{.}"/></xsl:template> is all the XSLT code you need.

The result with e.g. Saxon 12 will be <description value="&#xA;  This is a description on&#xA;  more than one line&#xA;"/>.

Hello,I thought I used Saxon, but I the library I used was Xalan. You are right, I have 
 with Saxon 12.5, and &X10; with Xalan.

The requirements you state are conflicting:
You say you want to keep the newline characters, but the expected result you show does not have the original leading and trailing whitespace characters, including the line breaks.
To get the result you show you need to do something like (in XSLT 2.0):
<xsl:template match="description"> 
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:attribute name="value" select="replace(., '^\s+|\s+$', '')"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template> 

Note that this keeps not only the line breaks between the lines, but also the indenting spaces. If you want to get rid of those too, there's more work to be done, maybe something like:
        <xsl:attribute name="value" select="replace(replace(., '^\s+|\s+$', ''), '&#10; +', '&#10;')"/>


Your translate() call is meaningless because it is replacing the character U+000A (newline) by the character U+000A (newline).
Your actual output differs from the desired output in two ways:
(a) Saxon has chosen to serialize the newline characters using decimal character references (&#10;) rather than hexadecimal character references (&#xa;). These are completely equivalent and any XML parser will treat them in the same way. If you really care, commercial editions of Saxon have an option to control this. But I think that all recent Saxon versions use the hexadecimal form anyway.
(b) The newlines and spaces at the beginning and end of the value have been retained. If you want to trim this, you can use the replace() function, for example: replace($input, '^\s*', '') => replace('\s*$', '').
Note also that your code is very unnecessarily verbose. The code:
<xsl:template match="/">
   <xsl:choose>
       <xsl:when test="description">      
          <xsl:element name="description">
             <xsl:variable name="temp">
                <xsl:value-of select="description"/>
             </xsl:variable>    
             <xsl:attribute name="value">            
                <xsl:value-of select="translate($temp, $new-line, '&#xA;')" />
             </xsl:attribute>               
          </xsl:element>
       </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
 </xsl:template>

could have been written as:
<xsl:template match="/description">
  <description value="{translate(., $newline, '&#xa;')}"/>
</xsl:template>


The problem I had was after I used the resulting XML file to parse it. The parser (Xerces) did not see the new lines with � characters , but saw it with the 
 characters.
